# Optimizing SQL Query which uses dates for filtering and joins

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I have a SQL query which I need to optimize as now it seems to run for ever.
I have ran it for more than 5 hours but it just doesn't seem to end.

```
SELECT 
a.HD_ID,
CASE WHEN date_from > b.date_tag THEN date_from
        ELSE b.date_tag
END date_from1,
CASE WHEN trunc(date_to)=b.date_tag THEN date_to
        ELSE b.date_tag + interval '23 hours, 59 minutes,59 seconds'
END date_to1
FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 b
ON (b.date_tag between trunc(date_from) and date_to) 
WHERE a.first_date between '2015-08-11' and sysdate-3;
```

I think the issue is because of the date fields but I am not aware of any way to optimize date operations.
Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Try adding indices to `date_tag`, `date_from`, and `date_to`, as well as `first_date`.  You can also run `EXPLAIN` before and after to see if it helped.

Comment: add tag of the DBMS you are using

Comment: There is no `sysdate` in PostgreSQL. Please add the output of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT ...` to the question.

Comment: In addition to the requests for explain plans etc - the join from Table1 to Table2 appears to only reference table2 and date_from / date_to - but no source of those values is given (no table alias, so are they input parameters?) If neither field is from table1 it would cause a Cartesian effect. Is a Cartesian the thing that is required, or is one of those fields from table1?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a lot of duplicates with this code? You are just joining them by date, something that is rarely done.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
SELECT 
a.HD_ID,
CASE WHEN date_from > b.date_tag THEN date_from
ELSE b.date_tag
END date_from1,
CASE WHEN trunc(date_to)=b.date_tag THEN date_to
ELSE b.date_tag + interval '23 hours, 59 minutes,59 seconds'
END date_to1
FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 b
ON trunc(date_from) >= b.date_tag <= date_to
WHERE '2015-08-11' >= a.first_date <= sysdate-3;
```